# Should TrustManager trust expired certificate from TrustStore?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have the following kotlin code, which is executed as android application:

```
val expiredCertificate: X509Certificate = ...
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
putCert(keyStore, expiredCertificate)
val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm).apply {
    init(keyStore)
}
val trustManager = trustManagerFactory.trustManagers.firstOrNull() as? X509TrustManager
val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS").apply {
    init(null, arrayOf(trustManager), SecureRandom())
}
```

In short:

1. I get (no matter how) expired x509-certificate,
2. put it in KeyStore,
3. pass the store to SslContext as store of trusted certificates.

As a result, my ssl-engine has trustStore with expired certificate.

Next, I initiate ssl-connection with backend and receive server`s certificate chain with this exact certificate that resides in trust store.

The question is: upon validating the chain, should ssl-engine check expiration of received certificate?
On the one hand, the certificate is trusted (resides in trust store thus is trust anchor), on the other hand, it is expired. Should ssl-engine trust the certificate or not?

P.S. The behaviour I actually observe is the following: the certificate is handled with *android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager* which delegates to *com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl* which puts my certificate to a variable with self-explanatory name *trustAnchors* and does not perform any checks so that my expired certificate is trusted. I wonder whether this is bug or feature.

Comment: What happens, if you use this imported and expired certificate?

Comment: TrustManager trusts certificate chain received from server, tls-connection is entablished and works as if everything is fine.

Comment: Regarding the behavior you are observing with Android's RootTrustManager and TrustManagerImpl, it is difficult to say whether it is a bug or a feature without more context about the specific use case and design decisions. However, it is generally not recommended to trust expired certificates in production systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should ssl-engine trust the certificate or not?

Yes, one must be able to accept expired certificates if it explicitly said. A human would accept this risk on a popup window, and a program which is not able to ask this question to the user would rely on the TrustStore content.

From [RFC 5246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) which says :

```
 For example, if a peer decides to accept an
 expired certificate (perhaps after confirming this with the user) and
 wants to continue the connection, it would not generally send a
 certificate_expired alert.
```